# Getting Repository dependencies

Tags: oracle, repository, rdbms, informatica

I'm using Informatica with Oracle RDBMS. Lately I've been struggling a bit.

I got an assignment to query the dependencies between each Model/Workflow , so the desired result will look something like this:

```
GRAND_MODEL | GRAND_WORKFLOW | WAIT_4_MODEL | WAIT_4_WORKFLOW
 DWH_Model1     WF_workflow1    DWH_Model3      WF_Workflow3_1
 DWH_Model1     WF_workflow1    DWH_Model4      WF_Workflow4_1
 DWH_Model2     WF_workflow2_1  DWH_Model1      WF_Workflow1
```

Which means, `WF_workflow1` in model `DWH_Model1` waits for workflow `WF_Workflow3_1` in model `DWH_Model3` ETC....

We have 3 types of workflows , `DELTA` (will contains the word `DELTA`) `DWH` (same here) and `CALC`(same here). A workflow that waits uses an `EVENT` that will contain both of the models names, and a workflow that flags contain a `CMD` that contain the `grand_model` name.

So far We've come up with this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT OA.SUBJ_NAME AS GRAND_MODEL,
                OL.SUBJ_NAME AS WAIT_4_MODEL_NAME,
                REP.WORKFLOW_NAME AS WAIT_4_WORKFLOW_NAME,
                A.FLAG_NAME,
                CASE
                  WHEN INSTR(UPPER(A.FLAG_NAME), 'DWH') > 0 THEN
                   'DWH'
                  WHEN INSTR(UPPER(REP.WORKFLOW_NAME), 'DELTA') > 0 THEN
                   'DELTA'
                  ELSE
                   'CALC'
                END CONNECTION_NAME
  FROM OPB_SUBJECT@TO_INFORMATICA_ADMIN OL,
       OPB_SUBJECT@TO_INFORMATICA_ADMIN OA,
       OPB_TASK@TO_INFORMATICA_ADMIN T,
       OPB_TASK@TO_INFORMATICA_ADMIN TL,
       OPB_TASK_INST@TO_INFORMATICA_ADMIN TI,
       REP_SESSION_INSTANCES@TO_INFORMATICA_ADMIN REP,
       (SELECT T.TASK_ID,
               SUBSTR(T.ATTR_VALUE,
                      LENGTH(T.ATTR_VALUE) + 2 -
                      INSTR(REVERSE(T.ATTR_VALUE), '/')) FLAG_NAME
          FROM OPB_TASK_ATTR@TO_INFORMATICA_ADMIN T
         WHERE T.TASK_TYPE = 60
           AND INSTR(REVERSE(T.ATTR_VALUE), '/') > 0) A,
       (SELECT T.TASK_ID,
               T.SUBJECT_ID,
               SUBSTR(T.PM_VALUE,
                      LENGTH(T.PM_VALUE) + 2 -
                      INSTR(REVERSE(T.PM_VALUE), '/')) FLAG_NAME
          FROM OPB_TASK_VAL_LIST@TO_INFORMATICA_ADMIN T
         WHERE INSTR(REVERSE(T.PM_VALUE), '/') > 0) L
 WHERE OL.SUBJ_ID = L.SUBJECT_ID
   AND A.TASK_ID = T.TASK_ID
   AND T.SUBJECT_ID = OA.SUBJ_ID
   AND A.FLAG_NAME = L.FLAG_NAME
   AND OL.SUBJ_NAME <> OA.SUBJ_NAME
   AND L.TASK_ID = TL.TASK_ID
   AND TL.TASK_ID = TI.TASK_ID
   AND TI.WORKFLOW_ID = REP.WORKFLOW_ID
```

This query works! The problem is, I'm getting worklets as workflows as well, so some of the times the last joins fails. I don't know how to avoid it..

Comment: can you provide an example output from this SQL that shows the failing condition (i.e. the worklets)?

Comment: It's not exactly failing, it's just that the worklets ids doesn't appear in the workflows tables.